# References to "Nos" in "Philosophical Papers and Letters" by Leibniz, edited by Loemker

Tags: reference-request, leibniz

Does anyone know what text is being referenced here. There are many times they cite like (Nos. 5,6,7) but there is no reference to this text in the bibliography, nor anywhere in the text. Google similarly has nothing other than links to the book.

If anyone could tell me what this is I would be very grateful.

Comment: Thank you! This was killing me

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Please answer in...well...answers, not comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbering is given within the contents on the left and each section is numbered accordingly:

[image]
[image]

Definitely, the reader should have been explicitly informed about this arrangement.

Make sure that you use the corrected second edition; the first edition contains clear mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that they are the internal references to the chapters that organize Leibniz's material.